# Module for executing postponed initialization code

Tags: perl

Where to put initialization code (connecting to databases, generating stuff, loading data files, etc)?

Here are some existing options:

1. Put it into the module in question. This will execute the code in `BEGIN{}` when the module is `use`d

(+) Good encapsulation.

(-) Everything is tied to databases, configuration, specific file locations etc. Hard to isolate unit tests, even harder to run code snippets to find bugs, as in `perl -MFoo -d -we 'Foo->new'`

2. Put it into separate script (`startup.pl` etc)

(-) Code away from where it's used, easy to forget something.

(-) Initializing all-or-nothing.

3. `startup()` (or other name) routine in every module in project.

(-) still easy to forget to run it.

4. Use Perl's built in INIT block.

Here's the problem (same for Apache, of course):

```
 bash$ plackup -e 'use warnings; INIT{ warn "foo"; }; sub { warn "here"; return [200, [], []] };'
 Too late to run INIT block at (eval 7) line 1.
 HTTP::Server::PSGI: Accepting connections at http://0:5000/
 here at (eval 7) line 1.
 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2014:14:18:08 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"
```

Note the `Too late to call INIT` warning and no sign of "foo" in output.

Now I'd like to have a module which is used as follows:

In project's module:

```
use Init::Queue sub { 
    get_dbh(); 
    load_file();
    build_cache(); 
}; # postpone till explicitly called
```

In production/initialization code:

```
Init::Queue->startup(); 
# this executes all startup blocks,
# in order of appearance
```

Is there such a module? If not, is it needed? Or is there a simpler approach which I've overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer is 'it depends'. But personally, I tend to take an 'init on first use' approach. That's relatively easy when you're doing it Object Oriented - hook the constructor and get it to set things up.

For non OO perl, I actually tend to do something like:

```
{
    my $thing_to_init;
    sub init { 
        $thing_to_init = 1;      
    }

   sub call_some_function {
       init() unless defined $thing_to_init; 

        #do everything else
    }
}
```

Because it's inside a closure, `$thing_to_init` isn't accessible from the module namespace, but you could either: manually call the `init()` sub, or just let the thing init itself when it fires up.

Comment: Yes, lazy init is the one I missed. But I also want my application to fail loudly on startup if it's deficient and/or misconfigured. I didn't state it in the original message though.

Comment: Hmm, difficult one then. BEGIN block in module would seem sensible, but I'm not sure how much config you could pass to it at that point. Maybe have a 'default config' and an an override to reconfigure?